# What's wrong of my way of changing colors of text using external links in CSS

Tags: html, css

Trying to change the colors of my h1 and h3 to blue by using external links yet it never works. Please help me.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EAF6F6;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}

h3 {
  color: blue;
}

hr {
  background-color: none;
  border-style: dotted none none;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 5%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rick's Personal Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing='20'>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="WeChat Image_20220221090440.jpg" alt="a picture of Rick"></td>
      <td>
        <h1>
          <center>Rick Yang</center>
        </h1>
        <p><em>The <strong><a 
    href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerlifting">powerlifter</a></strong>.</em></p>
        <p>I am an amateur powerlifter and strength trainer.
          <br>I love coding and just started learning them</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <h3><strong>Education</strong></h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean Rick with: `change with using external links` ? Can you explain what you expect?

Comment: Yes. I write my main code in one page(for the essential texts of my websites). For the editing/styling (such as changing header color or changing the image background color) I would write in another page and eventually link the styling page to the main page to apply all the styling effects on texts/pictures etc.. That's what I mean by external links.

Comment: You mean that you include `style.css` file in your code?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean by external link

Comment: It seems that your external css file is not loaded. can you check in the dev tools? Or open your website and try to open the file: for example: `http://localhost/css/style.css`. If not works then you have problem with the path.

Answer (score 1):

you not define in style Tages of CSS.
1:- First you write all HTML of your page.
2:- When this is Ok then define style tag and copy all CSS code between style.

Example:-

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rick's Personal Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table cellspacing='20'>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="WeChat Image_20220221090440.jpg" alt="a picture of Rick"> 
 </td>
      <td>
        <h1>
          <center>Rick Yang</center>
        </h1>
        <p><em>The <strong><a 
    href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerlifting">powerlifter</a> 
</strong>.</em></p>
        <p>I am an amateur powerlifter and strength trainer.
          <br>I love coding and just started learning them</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr>
  <h3><strong>Education</strong></h3>
</body>


 <style type="text/css">


body {
  background-color: #EAF6F6;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
}

h3 {
  color: blue;
}

hr {
  background-color: none;
  border-style: dotted none none;
  border-color: grey;
  height: 0px;
  border-width: 5px;
  width: 5%
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand. I am using external link so I thought I don't need to define no style. Instead I only need to write the code on style in a separate page and link the page to apply the style.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, yet the code is not changing the color of h1 h3 neither..

Answer (score 0):

I am Again. Thank you Reply me.
Replace  Your link Html line With this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

This well help you. For External CSS file.
If you want change color when curser over on h1 and h3 than use hover Properties.
If you want continuesly changing color than use @keysframe in style.